# Averaging different frequencies

Tags: fft, audio

How does one average a group of frequencies? Frequencies taken for example using FFT.

That is, given n frequencies over m time intervals (n $\leq$ m), how should one "interpolate" between those frequency values so that one gets a response that's "average", rather than direct.

I don't mean to calculate the average of all those frequencies and then assign every time interval the average value. Rather, how to take the response of those frequencies closer to "following an average", i.e. a more slowly changing and more "averaging" response.

Pseudocode?

Comment: Do you want to average over time or over frequency, or both?

Comment: @MattL. "given n frequencies over m time intervals (n ≤ m)", so both. Each time interval has one frequency, which may be different or the same as in the others.

Comment: Moving average should work...Isn't that a low pass filter?